# Error while updating property 'marginRight' in shadow node of type: RCTView null Unknown value: 10

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

**Getting error for this code. [Image Attached]**

```
const Message = ({ message }) => {

    const isMe = message.user.id === myID;

    return (
        <View 
            style={[styles.container, isMe ? styles.leftContainer : styles.rightContainer]}>
            <Text style={{color: isMe ? 'black' : 'white'}}>{message.content}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: '#4D5F75',
        padding: 10,
        margin: 10,
        borderRadius: 15,
        maxWidth: '75%'
    },
    leftContainer: {
        backgroundColor: '#4D5F75',
        marginLeft: 10,
        marginRight: 'auto'

    },
    rightContainer: {
        backgroundColor: '#BFC3CA',
        marginLeft: 'auto',
        marginRight: '10'
    }
});



export default Message;
```

And when I save and load the emulator it turns off.

> Error while updating property 'marginRight' in shadow node of type:
> RCTView
>
> null
>
> Unknown value: 10

Comment: Give marginRight: 10

Answer (score 0):

Inside

```
rightContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#BFC3CA',
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginRight: '10'
}
```

Change this `marginRight: '10'` to this: `marginRight: 10`